Simplifying expression using assumptions
Given that $$x_1 = \frac{-\beta_1 + \beta_1\delta_1 + \beta_2\delta_2}{2\delta_1\beta_1}$$, simplify the expression $$1 - \frac{\beta_1 - \beta_1\beta_2}{\beta_1\delta_1}$$ and verify that the simplified form is equal to $2x_1$.
Consider the following Mathematica code snippet, which does not seem to have the intended effect:
Assuming[(-\[Beta]1 + \[Beta]1 \[Delta]1 + \[Beta]2 \[Delta]2)/(
  2 \[Beta]1 \[Delta]1) == 
  x1, (1 - (\[Beta]1 - \[Beta]2 \[Delta]2)/(\[Beta]1 \[Delta]1))]

How to do it?

\[Beta]1  \[Delta]1) == 
  x1, (1 - (\[Beta]1 - \[Beta]2  \[Delta]2)/(\[Beta]1  \[Delta]1)) == 
   2 x1 // FullSimplify]```

The assumptions given in Assuming or $Assumptions are only used by functions within their scope that take the option Assumptions (e.g., Simplify, FullSimplify, Integrate). Your Assuming does not contain any function that uses the option Assumptions. However, in this particular case, just adding Simplify or FullSimplify wont achieve the desired result.

Your second question is easy to answer:
sl = Solve[(-\[Beta]1 + \[Beta]1 \[Delta]1 + \[Beta]2 \[Delta]2)/(2 \
\[Beta]1 \[Delta]1) == x1, \[Delta]1][[1, 1]]

(* \[Delta]1 -> (-\[Beta]1 + \[Beta]2 \[Delta]2)/((-1 + 2 x1) \[Beta]1) *)

Then
1 - (\[Beta]1 - \[Beta]2 \[Delta]2)/(\[Beta]1 \[Delta]1) /. 
  sl // Simplify

(* 2 x1  *)

Done.
The first question is more complex since the expression you give is already simple. So, your action depends on the form in which you want to see this expression. That is, it depends on your preferences. Here are a few simple possibilities:
expr = 1 - (\[Beta]1 - \[Beta]2 \[Delta]2)/(\[Beta]1 \[Delta]1)




expr // Simplify

(* (\[Beta]1 (-1 + \[Delta]1) + \[Beta]2 \[Delta]2)/(\[Beta]1 \[Delta]1) *)


expr // Expand
(* 1 - 1/[Delta]1 + ([Beta]2 [Delta]2)/([Beta]1 [Delta]1) *)

Together[Take[expr // Expand, {1, 2}]] + (expr // Expand // Last)
(* (-1 + [Delta]1)/[Delta]1 + ([Beta]2 [Delta]2)/([Beta]1 [Delta]1) *)


Have fun!
